# Best practices to merge docker volumes content?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Since docker does not seem to allow us to do something like this :

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    php-apache:
        image: php:7.2.1-apache
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./sources:/var/www/html
            - ./sources_bis:/var/www/html
```

with :

```
.
├── sources
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── image.png
│   │   └── logo.png
│   └── index.php
└── sources_bis
    └── images
        └── image.png
```

What would be the best practise if i want my container to include sources directory content and then merge the content of the directory sources_bis ?

The idea behind this question is to be able to share the same base code between different projects running through container but also being able to do specific developments for each project. So if you have any other practises that could help me doing this, i will take it !

Comment: You'd do this exactly the same way you would if Docker wasn't involved; probably having a script to `cp -a` both directories into a common directory.

Comment: Of course a simple cp would work but i would like to be able to modify things in sources_bis without the need to do a cp after every single change. Also, if i remove a file from sources_bis, i'll need to restart my container and then do a cp. I don't think it's a really good way to work, and i don't want to bother devs who works with me with that kind of practices, any other idea ?

Comment: Docker has nothing to help this.  Volumes and bind mounts are a simple "put host directory A in container location B, hiding everything there" and there is no sort of merge or overlay functionality.